# How do I use "else-if" with initializer in C++17?

Tags: c++, if-statement, lambda, c++17

From the *cpp reference*:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if, 
It does not seem that I can do this:

```
if (cond)
{}
else if (init; cond)  // <<--- init not allowed with "else if"
{}
```

I got around it in a rather silly way:

```
if (cond)
{}
else if ([]() -> bool
{
    init;
    if (cond)
    {
        // Do something in the same scope as 'init'
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}())
{}
```

Am I missing something obvious here about how to do this "correctly" using C++17?

Comment: You seem like you're citing cppreference saying you can't do that, but cppreference does not say that.

Comment: You most probably have a syntax error. You should show the actual code. You can have an initializer in any `if` statement. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/2hcTRc

Comment: Could have just tried it

Comment: I think I phrased my question poorly.  Sorry about that -- I guess I was trying to understand IF this was a hole in the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a "else if" statement. Instead it's a separate `else` statement followed by a separate `if` statement.

A chain like

```
if (cond1)
{
    ...
}
else if (cond2)
{
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (cond1)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    if (cond2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So using `else if (init; cond)` should be possible to do.

Comment: You are right -- and thank you.  The error I was getting was caused because I was initializing a variable twice, which was not reflected in my question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> init not allowed with "else if"

Why not?

The following code is heavily un-useful but compile perfectly with both g++ and clang++

```
int main ()
 {
   if ( bool cond {false} ; cond )
      ;
   else if ( bool cond {true} ; cond )
      ;
 }
```

As explained by Some programmer dude, `else if` isn't separate C/C++ statement: it's an `else` followed by another statement. So the following `if` isn't conditioned from the preceding `else`.